# Restrain number of rows shown in select

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap v4, added multiple items to `<select>`, trying to style it.

What is the proper way to restrain number of items shown?

So it doesn't look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
             <option value="1">This is select number 1</option>
             <option value="2">This is select number 2</option>
             <option value="3">This is select number 3</option>
             <option value="4">This is select number 4</option>
             <option value="5">This is select number 5</option>
             <option value="6">This is select number 6</option>
             <option value="7">This is select number 7</option>
             <option value="8">This is select number 8</option>
             <option value="9">This is select number 9</option>
             <option value="10">This is select number 10</option>
             <option value="11">This is select number 11</option>
             <option value="12">This is select number 12</option>
       </select>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but that makes the whole Select looks bugged.

Comment: Try checking the JS file and go to the <select> tag and usually it is set to 'auto' change to how many you want visible i.e. 8